# How to create a login/sign up page in WordPress as the front page

Tags: wordpress

1. Essentially, what I am trying to do is to have a login/sign-up page at the front of my website. This means someone has to either log in or sign-up first before accessing the rest of the website. Exactly like how Facebook has done it on its website.
2. The login and sign-up forms work, however, the user's account is not displayed at the top bar navigation even after signing up.

I am using the Forminator plugin and can't figure out how to do this. I have already created the forms. I also do not want to pay for any pro version of a plugin at the moment.
I also tried to look for a solution to try and display the user's account profile on the top bar navigation but have found no solution as well.
I am willing to use any different plugins if they will help me solve the issue.

Comment: There are plugins on the WordPress repository to add front end login and signup, like: [Front End Only Users](https://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-only-users/) and many more.

Comment: Assuming you have PHP experience, I would advise this: For the login form use `wp_login_form()`, for the signup I think you might have to handle it yourself with `signup_user()`. It allows you to signup users, won't give you a from for it though.